# Admob google play services migration

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, processing

I was hoping to get some help with an issue I'm facing migrating to the new google play services for admob.

I used processing.org, but in Android Studio, and the ads were working fine for both banner and interstitial. But now I'm getting the following error when I try to display and avert.

The adload works ok, as I the message appears on  my screen, but when the addcount = 300 and the if statement requirements are met, it stated isLoaded must be called on the main UI. As far as I'm aware, I only have one UI as it is just one java file imported from processing. Is this a limitation of processing or is there a possible work around?

```
   Process: processing.test.jellycrush, PID: 24705
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: isLoaded must be called on the main UI thread.
            at bvz.b(SourceFile:251)
            at zk.e(SourceFile:403)
            at aao.onTransact(SourceFile:66)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.aq$a$a.isReady(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.av.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
            at processing.test.jellycrush.jellycrush.test1(jellycrush.java:738)
            at processing.test.jellycrush.jellycrush.draw(jellycrush.java:328)
            at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
            at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
            at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my code (well the relevant bits)

```
package processing.test.jellycrush;

//the draw section

public class jellycrush extends PApplet {

 public void draw() {

addcount++;

  if(addcount==300) {
                  test1();
              }
}

//the admob code

 private static final String LOG_TAG = "InterstitialSample";
    //
//


    private InterstitialAd interstitial;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = getWindow();
        RelativeLayout adsLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        addcount++;

        //create add
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        window.addContentView(adsLayout, lp2);

        //set the listener

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                Toast.makeText(jellycrush.this, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorcode) {
            }
            // Only implement methods you need.
        });
    }
        public void test1(){

            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown.");
            }


    }
```

I have followed instruction on updating the manifest file to set the main UI, but still no luck

Any help would be great!

see comment below, I can get the advert to display using the following code, just not when I want it to display

```
 interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {



        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded");
            Toast.makeText(jellycrush.this, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //interstitial.show();
        }



        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        }



    });
```

Comment: ok, so Made an amendment which almost got me there.. if I place  interstitial.show(); in the setAdListner function, the advert displays, just not when I when I want it to display. but at least it proves the services are set up correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** call `interstitial.show()` on `AdListener.onAdLoaded()`. Poor user experience and you will get your account banned.

You are getting the error because you are attempting to call interstitial.show() from a Thread other than the man UI thread.

You need to queue your call to `interstitial.show()` so that it runs on the main UI thread. Best way to achieve that is to use `runOnUIThread(myRunnable)`. EG

```
private void showMyInterstitial() {
  runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      intersitial.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would want to put the ad load code in it's own class that extends runnable. But a quick sample of how to get UI code off the main thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //ad stuff
    }
});
```